# Deploying WCF Web Service from File System to IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

Is there anything special i need to do to deploy this service in IIS, right now I publish the site to the file system from visual studio then created the application in IIS.

I can browse to the .svc file in my web browser but i cant call any of the operations.

This is the Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>     
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding" openTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxBufferPoolSize="9223372036854775807" maxReceivedMessageSize="9223372036854775807">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None" />
          <reliableSession enabled="true" />
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
          <dataContractSerializer />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors >
        <behavior>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="MerlonWebServiceAPI.MGWS">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://SingleWSDL/MGWS"
          bindingConfiguration="" name="wsHttp" contract="MerlonWebServiceAPI.IService" >
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />       
      </service>
    </services>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>  
</configuration>
```

This is the IService

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://SingleWSDL/MGWS")]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "ActiveCalls")]
    List<ActiveCall> GetActiveCalls();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "PointStatus")]
    List<PointStatus> GetPointStatus();

    [OperationContract]
    bool Validate(string username, string password);
}
```

I can dump the full wsdl file if required thanks in advance for any assistance

Comment: Post your solution and give link!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to just adjust the app Pool for the "Web Site" you have deployed to look at the correct framework.  In my case it is almost always V2, whereas I require to change it to V4.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i already have the App Pool set to V4

Comment: How are you trying to call the service? I don't mean to insult, but sometimes when you create the reference wrong (Web Service vs. Service), you get the service, but it does not work.   What message are you getting exactly?

Comment: I am trying to call the service through my web broswer but so far have not been able to get it to execute, the svc file hosts okay but i cant call any methods via the brower, the Mex is working fine and i can call methods from the WCF test client

Comment: Apologising upfront, but have you tried some of the other obvious ones, like checking from/on the server, checking whether firewall is blocking something, turn off custom errors (for remote - See: <customErrors mode="Off"/>), set as safe browser list, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write how are you trying to access the service. Do you use WCF Test Client? If so then it should work when you add service url. Test client will show you all methods exposed by wsHttpBinding.

But if you are trying to make a http REST call to the service, there is no endpoint listening.
You should also expose webHttpBinding endpoint. I have not tested it but this should do

```
<endpoint address="rest" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://SingleWSDL/MGWS" bindingConfiguration="" name="restHttp" contract="MerlonWebServiceAPI.IService" />
```

Then you could access it typing `http://{serviceurl}/rest/`.
Hope it helps.

Comment: If i use the WCF test client it works fine but my goal is to be able to call the method from both a browser and the test client.

Comment: This worked but i also had to add resfulbehaviour to the endpoint